# How to remove open access after copying File?

Tags: java, file

I want to remove open access after copying File and revoke the access again after performing some task

```
File srcfile = Paths.get(source, fileName).toFile();
File destFile = Paths.get(destination, fileName).toFile();
Boolean bool = destFile.setExecutable(false);
```

Bool is always returning false

Comment: I'm a little perplexed as to what you mean by "removing open access." Do you mean you want to restrict open, read, and write permissions to users, like by using the `java.security` namespace? We need more information and you need to be more specific.

Comment: BTW, where did you copy the file in your code?